# Wordpress shortcode in simple lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I am using the following code to display a lightbox when a customer adds a product to their cart in WooCommerce. It works, but the problem is that I need to display a shortcode or PHP in the lightbox, and I can't make it work with the standard do_shortcode.

Right now it just displays a simple text, but I would need to display more info like product names, images and stuff. Is it possible to detach the lightbox markup, so it's not directly in the jQuery code, but separate, so I can use normal HTML/PHP?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('body').on('added_to_cart', function(e) {

        //prevent default action (hyperlink)
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get clicked link href
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        /*  
        If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document, 
        change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked

        If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
        (This will only happen the first time around)
        */

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists

            //place href as img src value
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

        }

        else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)

            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox" style="display:none">' +
                '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src woocommerce_bought_together
                    '<p>Produktet blev tilføjet til kurven!</p>' + 
                '</div>' +  
            '</div>';

            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }
        //show lightbox window
        $('#lightbox').fadeIn(200);

    });

    //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
    $(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() { //must use live, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
        $('#lightbox').fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

And CSS:

```
#content {
height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    #lightbox {
            /* keeps the lightbox window in the current viewport. position:fixed makes our overlay appear correctly in the current viewport, no matter the user’s position on screen (top or bottom of the page). This is where using the right DOCTYPE comes in handy. If IE runs in quirks mode due to the wrong DOCTYPE (or none at all), then our overlay won’t appear correctly.  */
            position:fixed; /* keeps the lightbox window in the current viewport */
            top:0; 
            left:0; 
            /* This makes our #lightbox div, which acts as the black overlay, cover the entire viewport no matter the end user’s screen resolution */
            width:100%; 
            height:100%; 
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
            text-align:center;
            z-index:9999;
            }
        /* we will add some text in the lightbox overlay stating they can click anywhere to have the lightbox window disappear */
        #lightbox p { 
            text-align:right;
            margin-right:20px;
            font-size:12px;
            width: 600px;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
            }
        #lightbox img {
            box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            /* Adding a max-width will shrink any high-resolution images we might be linking to. This helps to ensure all images fit into the viewport. */
            max-width:940px;
            }
```

Comment: `$('body').on('added_to_cart',` onclick?

Comment: Could you please explain? It shouldn't display on click, but on the added_to_cart action - it works, and that's not the issue.

Comment: _Is it possible to detach the lightbox markup, so it's not directly in the jQuery code, but separate, so I can use normal HTML/PHP?_ You could retrieve the lightbox's content via AJAX and inject it into it before displaying it.

Comment: Yes, I have also found other threads sugesting that, but I couldn't come up with a solution...